Can I use Apollo refetchQueries with a different client
We are in the process of migrating some calls from one server to another. I currently have an existing call that works with refetchQueries
const refetchQueries = ['MyComponent', { query: MY_QUERY, variables }];

const [myMutation] = useMutation(MY_MUTATION, {
    refetchQueries
});

We are introducing a new client that I pass to useMutation like this
const [myMutation] = useMutation(MY_MUTATION, {
    client: newClient,
    refetchQueries
});

But then the refetchQueries also happens on the new client, and we have not migrated MY_QUERY yet, so I still want it to happen on the old client? Is that possible?

No, that's not possible - Apollo Client has no concept of multiple parallel clients.
What you could try would be to keep one client, but have a split link that points some queries & mutations against your old server and some against the new server.
Keep in mind that query results from both servers would be merged into one shared normalized cache in that situation though - that could cause problems if both servers had overlapping data that is out of sync.

Keeping one client not possible in the current political situation. But I've found good compromise at the end, I just triggered the query with usequery. All have Ids so all got refreshed.
